# How to change output for N/A on tables using formattable package in R

Tags: r, dplyr, formattable

I'm making a table using the formattable package, here is the table and the code I have.

DataName = h1

[image: Image of data]

```
customGreen0 = "#DeF7E9"
customGreen = "#71CA97"
customRed = "#ff7f7f"

improvement_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                                   style = x ~ style(font.weight = "bold", 
                                                     color = ifelse(x > 0, customGreen, ifelse(x < 0, customRed,"black"))), 
                                   x ~ icontext(ifelse(x<0, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"),x)
)


formattable(h1, align =c("l","c","c","c","c", "c", "c", "c","c", "c","c", "c"), list(
  `Totals` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")), 
  `2011`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2012`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2013`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2014`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2015`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2016`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2017`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2018`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `2019`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `Average` = color_tile(customRed, customRed),
  `Change Since 2011` = improvement_formatter
))

h1[3,12] = "N/A"
```

This is the output I am getting

[image]
For row 3, column 12 I need this to be N/A but do not want it to be green or have a up/down arrow. Is it possible to turn black and/or have sideways arrow that signals that this data is not not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where `NA` does not have any color or arrow. In creating the `h1` data frame, I used `percent` and included `NA` as one of the values. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

```
library(formattable)

h1 <- data.frame(
  Totals = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  Y2011 = c(1230, 779, 37, 1176),
  Average = c(830,347,25,1140),
  Change = percent(c(-.01,.67,NA,.02), digits = 0)
)

customGreen0 = "#DeF7E9"
customGreen = "#71CA97"
customRed = "#ff7f7f"

improvement_formatter <- formatter("span", 
                                   style = x ~ style(font.weight = "bold", 
                                                     color = ifelse(x > 0, customGreen, ifelse(x < 0, customRed,"black"))), 
                                   x ~ icontext(ifelse(x < 0, "arrow-up", "arrow-down"), x)
)

formattable(h1, align =c("l", "c", "c", "c"), 
            list(
  `Totals` = formatter("span", style = ~ style(color = "grey",font.weight = "bold")), 
  `Y2011`= color_tile(customGreen, customGreen0),
  `Average` = color_tile(customRed, customRed),
  `Change` = improvement_formatter
))
```

Note that I left in red arrow up, green down as you intended.

[image: formattable table]

Comment: I copied and pasted your code to run in my environment. It works fine but now I'm getting this error: Originally the change column had 100% for row c, but now when i do h1[3,12] = "N/A" . I get  Error in x * 100 : non-numeric argument to binary operator. Any idea what i can do to fix that?  it worked before but im not to sure why.

Comment: Either or is fine, for my dataset i used dplyr to make the change column by subracting 2011-2019 and dividing by 2011.

Comment: I was using the h1[3,12] = "NA" . But how can i turn this into a numeric value so my table can be viewed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204574/discussion-between-fruitypebblepug-and-ben).